# Is it possible to load Saml2AuthenticationModule inside global.asax instead of web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, .net-4.7.2, sustainsys-saml2

Is it possible to load sustainsys Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule.Saml2AuthenticationModule inside global.asax instead of web.config?
Have anybody succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a new class with the attribute PreApplicationStartMethod and make use of HttpApplication.RegisterModule. This solved all this problem. Its now possible to have a education version of the software Iam developing with formsauth instead of saml